# How can I install vim plugins without close and reopen it the files I am working on?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have used Neo Vim as my main text editor for 2 weeks and I am currently used Vim Plug as my plugins manager. Let's say that I am working on 3 ruby files, and I want to install a plugin with Vim Plug.

The problem is I need to close all of the files I am working on, then open a new Neo Vim instance, and install the new plugin. I can work around with Tmux detach to install the new plugin. However, when I attach to my old TMUX session, my working files still can't recognize the new plugin.

Closing my working files and reopening them really disturb my productivity flow, therefore I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

> really disturb my productivity flow

Installing a plugin is not an everyday task (or, at least, mustn't be). So your argument doesn't apply.

> I have used Neo Vim as my main text editor for 2 weeks

And have too many plugins already? Well, it's like drinking under legal age: not uncommon yet evil.

> However, when I attach to my old TMUX session, my working files still can't recognize the new plugin.

Normally all plugins are loaded on Vim startup only. So you have to load it manually. If you're lucky then simple `:packloadall!` will help. But, of course, there's no guarantee that every plugin out there works well when loaded long after `VimEnter`.